# iBeacon - Disconnecting

Tags: ibeacon, android-ibeacon

I'm trying to configure some iBeacons. I have the Locate app by Radius and the LightBlue. But in both apps, the Beacons keeps disconnecting. On LightBlue it disconnects a few seconds after I connect.

On Locate it connects (or no?) but my distance range keeps ranging from excellent to not detected.

What configs should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be that your beacon is not transmitting frequently enough.  Beacons transmit at different frequencies from 10 Hz (good) down to 0.2 Hz or less (bad).  Some manufacturers of battery powered beacons make them transmit infrequently so the battery lasts longer.  This has serious impacts on ranging and distance estimates because so few samples of signal strength are available.